# Set an uilabel on callback function

Tags: ios, sockets, callback, uilabel

I whant to set the text of an uilabel on a callback of a cfsocket, but it don't work. Error is : "Use of undeclared identifier 'label'"
But this setText work in other functions, why not in this one?

Callback function :

```
static void receiveData(CFSocketRef s, CFSocketCallBackType type, CFDataRef address, const void *data, void *info)
{
    UInt8 *buff;

    NSLog(@"%ld",CFDataGetLength(data));

    CFDataGetBytes(data, CFRangeMake(0, CFDataGetLength(data)), buff);

    NSLog(@"%s",buff);

    [label setText:@"toto"];
}
```

Function where setText work :

```
- (IBAction)deconn:(id)sender
{
    if (conn_ok && socket && sock_addr) {
        CFSocketInvalidate(socket);
        [label setText:@"disconnected"];
        conn_ok = false;
        [sock_addr release];
    }

}
```

---

Ok, I have do this in my function :

```
socketViewController *toto = (id)info;
[toto.label setText:@"received msg"];
```

But it don't work, I receive en EXEC_BAD_ACCESS, and I have this in Log :

```
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
warning: Unable to restore previously selected frame.
(gdb)
```

I think it's a memory access problem, I have add `toto = nil;` at the end of the function but nothing change.

Answer (score 0):

`receiveData` is a function, not a method. You are trying to access a private ivar of an object. Had you used accessors (`self.label`) this would have been more clear. Use accessors.

You can use the `info` pointer to pass `self` to the callback so that you can access the label.

To configure the `info` pointer, you need to pass a context when you create the socket:

```
CFSocketContext context = { 0, self, NULL, NULL, NULL };
```

Now in your `CFSocketCreate...` call, you'll pass `&context` for the context parameter.

Rather than implement your own `CFSocket`, I typically recommend [cocoaasyncsocket](http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/). It provides a much easier interface.

Comment: @Xantra: 'self' is a keyword refering to this object. You can't use it as an identifier.

Answer (score 0):

`receiveData` is a static function so it won't have access to any object's member variables (ivars as they are called in Objective C).